# Soju yeast strains

Tags: yeast

I want to figure out how to make my own soju. It seems easy enough, rice, nuruk and yeast.

The one thing I havent figured out is what yeast strain soju is made with and if it is commercially available.

Answer (score 2):

This article from the IBD journal should help you get started on your hunt: 
[Influence of yeast strains on the physicochemical characteristics, methanol and acetaldehyde profiles and volatile compounds for Korean rice distilled spirit](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jib.268)

Here is the list of Yeasts tested in the paper:

- Lalvin Clos  Dry yeast
- Lalvin Clos  Dry yeast
- Lalvin Cy079 Dry yeast
- Lalvin DV10  Dry yeast
- Lalvin EC1118    Dry yeast
- Lalvin ICV D254  Dry yeast
- Lalvin D47   Dry yeast
- Lalvin R-HST Dry yeast
- Uvaferm BDX  Dry yeast
- 4347 Liquid yeast
- La Parisienne  Dry yeast